# Chains as integer valued functions

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

> We shall examine linear combinations of the form $c = \sum a_i \Delta_i^k$, where $a_i$ are integers (either positive or negative) and $\Delta_i^k$ are k-
> dimensional simplexes, and assume the sum to contain only a finite number of nonzero $a_i$. Such linear combinations are called integer valued k-dimensional chains (or simplicial integer-valued k-dimensional
> chains). Such a chain can be interpreted as an integer-valued function defined on the set of all k-dimensional simplexes, i.e. $c:\Delta_i^k \to a_i$
> for
> all $i$
>
> Visual Geometry and Topology, Anatoly Fomenko,page-22

I don't understand how the formal expansion of the chain was re-interpreted as function. Could someone explain, perhaps with an example , what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the free abelian group $\langle x,y,z \rangle$. An element of this group looks like $3x - 2y + 7z$, etc. In general, an element of the group looks like

$$
n_x x + n_y y + n_z z
$$

for $n_x, n_y, n_z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Of course, it's easy to see that these $n_x, n_y, n_z$ carry all the information of $n_x x + n_y y + n_z z$ already. Notice, for instance, that

$$
(n_x x + n_y y + n_z z) + (m_x x + m_y y + m_z z) = (n_x + m_x) x + (n_y + m_y) y + (n_z + m_z) z
$$

In this way we lose no information by identifying $n_x x + n_y y + n_z z$ with the function $n_{-} : \{x,y,z\} \to \mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, the previous computation shows that the usual (pointwise) definition of function addition
$n_{-} + m_{-}$ correctly reproduces addition in the group $\langle x,y,z \rangle$.

So we see $\langle x,y,z \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\{x,y,z\}}$, where by exponentiation I mean the space of functions $\{x,y,z\} \to \mathbb{Z}$. In general, $\langle S \rangle$ (the free abelian group generated by a set $S$) will be isomorphic to the group of functions $f : S \to \mathbb{Z}$ so that $f(s) \neq 0$ for finitely many $s$. We say that $f$ should have *finite support*.

In particular, when $S$ is the set of $n$-simplices in your space $X$, then the free abelian group on the $n$-simplices can be viewed as the group of functions from the $n$-simplices in $X$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ with finite support.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Where did you define S?  (for 2nd last para)

Comment: Is the idea that you treat the generating set elements as actual numbers?

Comment: S is any set, and the idea is to treat the elements of the generating set as "basis vectors" where we're only allowed to rescale by inetegers

Comment: Hmm could you explain the $f(s) \neq 0 $ condition a bit differently

Comment: Btw Idk I said before. I was in a rush and wrote something. What I wanted to say was your answer is really awesome!